# insertion, deletion and updation of observable elements using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am inserting a list like using knockout (observableArray):

1.apple **delete**
2.banana **delete**
3.mango **delete**
4.pineapple **delete**

When I delete "*2.banana **delete***", the list appears like:

1.apple **delete**
3.mango **delete**
4.pineapple **delete**

But I want it to appear like:

1.apple **delete**
2.mango **delete**
3.pineapple **delete**

The array is like: `this.list=ko.observableArray({num:1,name:apple});`
I am using "foreach" and "push" function to add more elements and "remove" function to delete.

Plz help me to make the list "num" update as I delete any element.

Comment: Do you actually need `num` as a property of each item? Is it okay for the template to take care of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $index inside of your foreach template to display the number. This is a feature new to Knockout 2.1, as shown here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/knockout-2-dot-1-is-out.html